# Discord.py warn command

Tags: python, parameters, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a warn command with discord.py. But I am having trouble with the string parameters for the proof and reason. I've tried googling this problem but couldn't come up with a solution, like using .format or .startswith. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Error:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: warn() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'proof'`

Code used:

````
async def warn(context,member: discord.Member,*,reason:str,proof:str):
    tests = collection.find({"name":"test"})
    for test in tests:
        extract = (test["id"])
    extract += 1
    collection.update_one(update={"$set": {"id":extract}},filter={})
    print(extract)
    print(member.name)
    warnings = {"id": extract, "member": member.name, "reason": reason, "type": "warn", "proof":proof}
    collection.insert_one(warnings)

    await context.send(f"Succesfully warned {member.name} for {reason}")
    await member.send(f"You were warned in Mega Studios for {reason}")```
````

Answer (score 0):

That error basically means your forgetting proof! It discord.py NEEDS all the variables that the ctx command requires! Try running the command using ALL for example:
`!warn @user <reason> <proof>`

Note: Make sure to replace Context with ctx Much easier!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make `proof` an optional argument, you should consider doing
What this will do is that if the argument `proof` isn't given, then set `proof` to `No reason`.

```
async def warn(context,member: discord.Member,*,reason:str,proof:str="No reason"):
```